# T-SQL: cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, linked-server

Error is:

> Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server

I'm trying to convert an Oracle SQL query to T-SQL. I get the error when I run this version of the query:

```
SELECT B.SAAS_ACTIVITY, A.LAST_NAME, A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME,  
        B.DIVISION_CODE, B.GRANT_YEAR, B.ACTIVITY_CODE, B.ACT_ACTIVITY_CODE,
        B.COST_CENTER, B.HOURS_BEG, B.LEAVE_ADJ_HOURS, B.CURRENT_MONTH,
        B.HOURS_BEG + B.LEAVE_ADJ_HOURS TOTAL_HOURS, B.PERCENT_WORK, 
        B.DIV_MONTHLY_SALARY, C.DIV_DESCRIPTION,
        B.DIV_SALARY_PLUS_FRINGE - B.DIV_MONTHLY_SALARY FRINGE, 
        B.DIV_SALARY_PLUS_FRINGE
  FROM ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.EMT_EMPLOYEE A, 
ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.LABOR_DISTRIB_MASTER_DETAIL B, 
    ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.ACT_DIVISION C
  WHERE A.ID = B.ID
       AND B.FISCAL_YEAR = :P_SFY
       AND B.DIVISION_CODE = C.DIVISION_CODE
       AND C.DIV_SFY = :P_SFY
       AND B.CURRENT_MONTH >= CASE WHEN :P_FROM_MONTH is null THEN 2 
            ELSE :P_FROM_MONTH
            END
       AND B.CURRENT_MONTH <= CASE WHEN :P_TO_MONTH is null THEN 13 
           ELSE :P_TO_MONTH
           END
       AND B.SAAS_ACTIVITY >= CASE WHEN :P__FROM_OFFICE  is null THEN '4701' 
           ELSE :P_FROM_OFFICE
           END
       AND B.SAAS_ACTIVITY <= CASE WHEN :P__TO_OFFICE  is null THEN '4705' 
           ELSE :P_TO_OFFICE
           END
       AND B.DIVISION_CODE >= CASE WHEN :P__FROM_DIV  is null THEN '0011' 
           ELSE :P_FROM_DIV
           END
      AND B.DIVISION_CODE <= CASE WHEN :P__TO_DIV  is null THEN '9999' 
           ELSE :P_TO_DIV
           END
      AND B.DIVISION_CODE <> '1050'
ORDER BY B.DIVISION_CODE, A.LAST_NAME, B.CURRENT_MONTH
```

But if remove the join to get the DIV_DESCRIPTION, and just go with the DIV_CODE, the query runs fine:

```
SELECT B.SAAS_ACTIVITY, A.LAST_NAME, A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME,  
        B.DIVISION_CODE, B.GRANT_YEAR, B.ACTIVITY_CODE, B.ACT_ACTIVITY_CODE,
        B.COST_CENTER, B.HOURS_BEG, B.LEAVE_ADJ_HOURS, B.CURRENT_MONTH,
        B.HOURS_BEG + B.LEAVE_ADJ_HOURS TOTAL_HOURS, B.PERCENT_WORK, 
        B.DIV_MONTHLY_SALARY, B.DIVISION_CODE,
        B.DIV_SALARY_PLUS_FRINGE - B.DIV_MONTHLY_SALARY FRINGE, 
        B.DIV_SALARY_PLUS_FRINGE
  FROM ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.EMT_EMPLOYEE A, 
     ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.LABOR_DISTRIB_MASTER_DETAIL B
  WHERE A.ID = B.ID
       AND B.FISCAL_YEAR = :P_SFY
       AND B.CURRENT_MONTH >= CASE WHEN :P_FROM_MONTH is null THEN 2 
            ELSE :P_FROM_MONTH
            END
       AND B.CURRENT_MONTH <= CASE WHEN :P_TO_MONTH is null THEN 13 
           ELSE :P_TO_MONTH
           END
       AND B.SAAS_ACTIVITY >= CASE WHEN :P__FROM_OFFICE  is null THEN '4701' 
           ELSE :P_FROM_OFFICE
           END
       AND B.SAAS_ACTIVITY <= CASE WHEN :P__TO_OFFICE  is null THEN '4705' 
           ELSE :P_TO_OFFICE
           END
       AND B.DIVISION_CODE >= CASE WHEN :P__FROM_DIV  is null THEN '0011' 
           ELSE :P_FROM_DIV
           END
      AND B.DIVISION_CODE <= CASE WHEN :P__TO_DIV  is null THEN '9999' 
           ELSE :P_TO_DIV
           END
      AND B.DIVISION_CODE <> '1050'
ORDER BY B.DIVISION_CODE, A.LAST_NAME, B.CURRENT_MONTH
```

Getting the DIV_DESCRIPTION is not absolutely critical, but I would like to understand why the error is occurring (I've worked with Oracle SQL much more than TSQL).  The column is defined as VARCHAR2(12) in both the ACT_DIVISION table and the LABOR_DISTRIB_MASTER_DETAIL table. IS this a data type mismatch thing, or something else?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

I recommend letting Oracle do all the grunt work for you by passing the query over via an `OPENQUERY`, its much easier on you (since you know Oracle syntax) and faster, since Oracle will do its own work on its own tables with its own indexes and only pass back the resultset to SQL Server.

Note since the query is contained in `' '` you have to double up the single `'` within it.

In doing this, the OLEDB driver should handle all the wonky datatype mapping for you.

Syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([ORCL_RIVENDELL],'SELECT B.SAAS_ACTIVITY, A.LAST_NAME, A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME,  
        B.DIVISION_CODE, B.GRANT_YEAR, B.ACTIVITY_CODE, B.ACT_ACTIVITY_CODE,
        B.COST_CENTER, B.HOURS_BEG, B.LEAVE_ADJ_HOURS, B.CURRENT_MONTH,
        B.HOURS_BEG + B.LEAVE_ADJ_HOURS TOTAL_HOURS, B.PERCENT_WORK, 
        B.DIV_MONTHLY_SALARY, C.DIV_DESCRIPTION,
        B.DIV_SALARY_PLUS_FRINGE - B.DIV_MONTHLY_SALARY FRINGE, 
        B.DIV_SALARY_PLUS_FRINGE
  FROM BP2K.EMT_EMPLOYEE A, 
       BP2K.LABOR_DISTRIB_MASTER_DETAIL B, 
       BP2K.ACT_DIVISION C
  WHERE A.ID = B.ID
       AND B.FISCAL_YEAR = :P_SFY
       AND B.DIVISION_CODE = C.DIVISION_CODE
       AND C.DIV_SFY = :P_SFY
       AND B.CURRENT_MONTH >= CASE WHEN :P_FROM_MONTH is null THEN 2 
            ELSE :P_FROM_MONTH
            END
       AND B.CURRENT_MONTH <= CASE WHEN :P_TO_MONTH is null THEN 13 
           ELSE :P_TO_MONTH
           END
       AND B.SAAS_ACTIVITY >= CASE WHEN :P__FROM_OFFICE  is null THEN ''4701'' 
           ELSE :P_FROM_OFFICE
           END
       AND B.SAAS_ACTIVITY <= CASE WHEN :P__TO_OFFICE  is null THEN ''4705'' 
           ELSE :P_TO_OFFICE
           END
       AND B.DIVISION_CODE >= CASE WHEN :P__FROM_DIV  is null THEN ''0011'' 
           ELSE :P_FROM_DIV
           END
      AND B.DIVISION_CODE <= CASE WHEN :P__TO_DIV  is null THEN ''9999'' 
           ELSE :P_TO_DIV
           END
      AND B.DIVISION_CODE <> ''1050''
ORDER BY B.DIVISION_CODE, A.LAST_NAME, B.CURRENT_MONTH')
```

If you need to pass parameters, here is the syntax:

Let's assume you have a parameter called @myDate you need to pass.

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME=GETDATE()

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
            FROM OPENQUERY([ORCL_RIVENDELL],''SELECT *
                                                FROM  BP2K.SOME_TABLE
                                                WHERE ACTIVITYDATE = '''''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@myDate,120)+''''' '')'

PRINT @SQL
--EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

All that said, you need to be VERY VERY careful using dynamic SQL, its dangerous if you do not control the input to these parameters.  You open yourself to SQL Injection attacks this way.  There are better/safer ways to pass parameters into `sp_executesql` but it would not work when using an `OPENQUERY`.  If you can validate the input using `ISDATE()` or `ISNUMERIC()` all the better, don't execute if they don't pass validation.  But your safest bet is to NEVER allow anyone but you to pass these parameters in, ever.

Comment: I've read that you can't pass parameters to OPENQUERY - is that correct?  I don't know if that will be a requirement, but I'd like to be sure either way.

Comment: You can with a dynamic query... I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm curious, though - I copied the Oracle table ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.ACT_DIVISION to SQL Server (2014) and rewrote the query to join B and C again (joining the Oracle table to the SQL Server table) and got the same error again.   So maybe there's something about the way I've written the query that's causing the error, and not something data-related?

Comment: Im not sure I follow.  You copied the table to sql server?  If the error is due to datatype mapping, its conceivable that it could still error out.  I don't know oracle well so i cant comment on all the syntax, aside from the old style joins and the `:P_` it all looks ok.  My gut tells me its datatypes the driver isnt handling well.

Comment: Yes - once I had the query working by just joining the ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.EMT_EMPLOYEE and ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.LABOR_DISTRIB_MASTER_DETAIL, just going with DIVISION_CODE instead of joining to ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.ACT_DIVISION to get the DIV_DESCRIPTION, I copied the ACT_DIVISION table to SQL Server (select * into BP2K_ACT_DIVISION from ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.ACT_DIVISION) and joined the ORCL_RIVENDELL..BP2K.LABOR_DISTRIB_MASTER_DETAIL table to that. In Oracle, DIVISION_CODE is defined as varchar2(12); in SQL Server, DIVISION_CODE is defined as varchar(12).

Comment: I'm assuming `LABOR_DISTRIB_MASTER_DETAIL.DIVISION_CODE` is also varchar2, so you've only eliminated 1/2 the issue.  I still feel its a mapping issue in the driver.  Can you implicitly convert it like this `AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),B.DIVISION_CODE) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),C.DIVISION_CODE)` in your join?